# Convert string to table in lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I am newbie in lua. I need to convert following string to lua table. How could I do this?

```
str = "{a=1, b=2, c={d=3,e=4} }"
```

I want to convert this string to lua table, so that I can access it like this:

```
print(str['a']) -- Output : 1
print(str['c']['d']) -- Output : 3
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could simply add a `str =` to the beginning of the string and let the interpreter load that string as a chunk for you. Note that `loadstring` doesn't run the chunk but returns a function. So you add `()` to call that function right away and actually execute the code:

```
loadstring("str = "..str)()
```

This would do the same thing:

```
str = loadstring("return "..str)()
```

If you don't generate the string yourself, that can be dangerous though (because **any** code would be executed). In that case, you might want to parse the string manually, to make sure that it's actually a table and contains no bad function calls.